# Query on version in R and major & minor component

Tags: r, version

Can any one please help me in understanding what major and minor component mean in a version in R

`version`

> 1.16.0

`version$major`

> 1

`version$minor`

> 16

When I am doing google search to check the latest version, I am getting 3.6.3. The Question that I am asking is 
1. What do the major and minor in component mean?
2. Why am I getting the version as 1.16.0 and not 3.6.3, has it something to do with accessing R from cloud server and doing it from the software directly downloaded on the system.

Comment: I'd guess you are using an alternative R implementation. Are you using Microsoft Azure?

Comment: @Roland You are right, I am using the Windows Server as a virtual machine on my system. Does the version differ when we load R on virtual machine?

Comment: The R version differs if you are using a different R version or implementation. You should know what you have installed.